# TypeScript + useRef<X|Y>: Type X is not assignable to type Y

Tags: reactjs, typescript

This simple component:

```
const Editable = ({multiline}: { multiline: boolean }) => {
    const ref = useRef<HTMLInputElement|HTMLTextAreaElement>(null);
    return <div>
        {multiline ? <textarea ref={ref}/> : <input ref={ref}/>}
    </div>
}
```

Have the following TypeScript errors:

```
Error:(7, 32) TS2322: Type 'RefObject<HTMLInputElement | HTMLTextAreaElement>' is not assignable to type 'string | ((instance: HTMLTextAreaElement | null) => void) | RefObject<HTMLTextAreaElement> | null | undefined'.
  Type 'RefObject<HTMLInputElement | HTMLTextAreaElement>' is not assignable to type 'RefObject<HTMLTextAreaElement>'.
    Type 'HTMLInputElement | HTMLTextAreaElement' is not assignable to type 'HTMLTextAreaElement'.
      Type 'HTMLInputElement' is missing the following properties from type 'HTMLTextAreaElement': cols, rows, textLength, wrap
Error:(7, 53) TS2322: Type 'RefObject<HTMLInputElement | HTMLTextAreaElement>' is not assignable to type 'string | ((instance: HTMLInputElement | null) => void) | RefObject<HTMLInputElement> | null | undefined'.
  Type 'RefObject<HTMLInputElement | HTMLTextAreaElement>' is not assignable to type 'RefObject<HTMLInputElement>'.
    Type 'HTMLInputElement | HTMLTextAreaElement' is not assignable to type 'HTMLInputElement'.
      Type 'HTMLTextAreaElement' is missing the following properties from type 'HTMLInputElement': accept, align, alt, checked, and 23 more.
```

The errors could be ignored using this following line:

```
const ref = useRef<any>(null);
```

How can `useRef` be used with the correct type and without errors?

Comment: It looks weird, but you might write: `const ref = useRef<HTMLInputElement & HTMLTextAreaElement>(null);` (note the intersection `&`)

Comment: @ford04 Amazing. Please post this as an answer!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### Solution 1: [Type assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#type-assertions)

```
const ref = useRef<HTMLInputElement | HTMLTextAreaElement>(null);
return (
    <div>
        {multiline ? <textarea ref={ref as React.RefObject<HTMLTextAreaElement>}/>:
            <input ref={ref as React.RefObject<HTMLInputElement>} />}
    </div>
)
```

`<textarea ... />` expects a [ref](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/51511d064c43b9beee70130b45cb9ae0e453eeb9/types/react/index.d.ts#L91-L93) that takes `HTMLTextAreaElement`. `HTMLTextAreaElement` contains [different properties](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/51511d064c43b9beee70130b45cb9ae0e453eeb9/types/react/index.d.ts#L2298-L2316) [than](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/51511d064c43b9beee70130b45cb9ae0e453eeb9/types/react/index.d.ts#L2086-L2122)  `HTMLInputElement`, so the [supertype](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/unions-and-intersections.html#union-types) `HTMLTextAreaElement | HTMLInputElement` cannot be assigned to *one* of the nodes. A type assertion is perfectly fine here. Pros: we are forced to narrow `ref` in a type-safe way. Cons: Type assertions are a bit verbose.

#### Solution 2: [Intersection type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/unions-and-intersections.html#intersection-types) for ref

```
const ref = useRef<HTMLInputElement & HTMLTextAreaElement>(null);
return (
    <div>
        {multiline ? <textarea ref={ref } /> :
            <input ref={ref} />}
    </div>
)
```

This works, as `HTMLInputElement` and `HTMLTextAreaElement` don't have conflicting property types (otherwise it would result in [`never`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#never)). Pros: more compact code. Cons: Make sure to narrow the element before. E.g. you might be able to invoke following code for `HTMLInputElement` leading to runtime errors:

```
ref.current && ref.current.cols // input does not have cols
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDGMA0cDecCuAzksgGbZFICippSGcAvnKVBCHAERSoacBQ-NBAB2heFQAmwGCgBGAGyRwAvHAAUeEPgUxgC4COWMAXLjjbd%20w0jNyIEJShFMAlKoB8ufnF9xhYvA8pKoExGQAPAASACoAsgAyAJIiYPgwVEogSCLwAD5wsYkxSAAeMACCPCiZSNm5HuoiOgquANw%20fjww%20FAu6p1%20fhHSAG4eg0NTOJZ6BkZwAPxwETBlstVwwSo4wXAohIi8MAB0ZADycgBW9DDR8Qkl5VWotfUwHswA9F4mk1MAlaGNJBJCkHZ7A5HdCnC7XW73RIpEFvHIfb6ff7DL5jCZDVz8RiCALiOBSGTyJQAJlCmgsOjmNiYZi0DOsRjsDicLkY7hUXhwkxJoJCakokSKyVS6VRuTgADJCg8npVqrKPk0Wu1JpMvl9gic0L0eLkAISGxyEQRDbq9fpY3wjYDjB3TWbs5TLVbrFCbba7MEYuB-QGhoHSkUQwNwH5E0MRHHOvF%20AlEwRAA)

Comment: Using `T1 & T2` is great - as I am using `ref.current.select()` which is available on both types. Thank you!

Comment: You're welcome. One note: Technically, the second solution is a bit "hackish", as you cannot have `HTMLInputElement` and `HTMLTextAreaElement` at the same time. For example, the compiler would reduce such types aggressively to `never` [in case of discriminanted union types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-9.html#intersections-reduced-by-discriminant-properties). Here it works fine and can be a concise way without assertion - but you might document this :-)